# How do I correctly store time over 24 hours in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, time, model, cakephp-2.0

I would like to store a period of time (20 minutes, 3 hours, 76 hours and 20 minutes...) with CakePHP.  What would be the appropriate way to do so?
If I use MySQL's `TIME` format, it's not necessarily database cross compatible, plus Cake expects it to be a time of day, with am/pm or 24 hour formatting.

Is the only option just to store it in seconds as an int and do the data crunch myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) method can help you to store time in UNIX timestamp format into the database. That you can easily use it later using [mktime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) method.